# Getting memory error in Python 3.8, using spider as my IDE

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to run a program that involves multiplying two large binary NumPy arrays of size 69496 times 511. My arrays are binary, and I am using Spyder as my IDE.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import re

def ip(A):
    B=A.transpose()
    C = np.dot(A, B)
    [a, b] = C.shape
    D=[]
    for i in range (a):
        print(i)
        for j in range (i+1, a):
            c= C[i, j]
            D.append(c)
    return(D)
```

So, the input "o" that I am giving to my function is a binary NumPy array of size 69496 times 511.

```
D = IP(o)
```

However, I am getting the following memory error:

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 36.0 GiB for an array with shape (69496, 69496) and data type float64
```

I have 16 GB RAM, and I have Windows 11. Can anybody give me suggestion about how to resolve this issue?

Comment: First of all, I highly doubt your arrays are actually binary, or boolean. The error message shows float64.

Comment: @Mercury ; Yes, the error message is saying that it is float64, But my input arrays only contains 0 and 1. Can you tell me how I can change float-type data into binary data?

Comment: You can convert it with [astype](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) to your desired type, like `o.astype(np.bool)`.

Comment: @Mercury : I tried o.astype(np.bool), but I am getting the same error.

Comment: Possibly because the arrays are still too big. The dot product between A and A.T itself should initially make a copy of A, and then a lot of memory needs to be allocated for internal matmul and to store the (69496, 69496) output (This is almost 5GB itself). You might need a more efficient algorithm here --- like I can easily tell that you are finding the upper triangle of A's self inner product, so maybe you don't need to do the full dot product here.

Comment: Using a sparse matrix is not an option ?

Comment: and `o.astype(np.bool)` should not produce the same error since `o` do not have the same shape as `np.dot(A,B)`

Comment: @obchardon ; How to use sparse matrix? can you elaborate? I am new to programming. Thanks.

Comment: @obchardon ; o definitely would not be of the shape np.dot(A,B). However, I am getting the same error.

Comment: A sparse matrix only store the non zero value. For each non zero value we store a triplet (row_position,column_position,value). So if your matrix contains a lot more zero value than non zero value, then a sparse matrix could be a good option.

Answer (score 0):

what you actually want is this function:
you dont need to calculate the a x aT, since you have huge matrix, it finally gonna need big memory size. you could set the dtype as uint16 , but any way finally still the size is huge (since you have huge number of row)

```
def ip(a):
    m, n = a.shape
    c = []
    for i in range(m):
            c.extend(np.dot(a[i + 1:], a[i]).tolist())
    return c
```

writing like this will help not to use big memory, but my recommendation would be to as well return as numpy array, did not get why you store as list, however I kept it as you wanted as output.

**output as numpy array:**

```
def ip(a):
    m, n = a.shape
    c = np.zeros(sum(range(m)), dtype=np.uint16)
    offset = ((np.arange(m - 1) * m) - np.cumsum(np.arange(m - 1) ))
    for i, off_set in enumerate(offset):
        c[off_set: off_set + m - i - 1] = np.dot(a[i + 1:], a[i])
    return c
```

*PS: notice even though your data is uint8 (as you mentioned) your output could be 16bit, since the columns are more than 256.*

Comment: Thanks for helping. I am still getting the memory error.

Comment: This implementation uses the minimum possible memory reqired (second version) are you sure you have enough memory just to have you output? If not partiallt calculate and wite to disk.

Comment: for the dimeneion you provided, your output is going to take 4.5 GB of memory. the benefit of the solution is that you could give partially your input and save to disk if you do not have enough memory. if you sure that matrices are sparse you could change the np.uint16 to uin8 and use half memory but that is all.

Comment: Thanks! How can I know if I have enough memory to get my output?

Comment: which os you are using, on linux open top, in windows open your taskbar and look at available memory or in mac look at activity monitor (memory section)